# Probability of sampling a sub graph

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

Given a set $G$ of size $|G|$ and given a subset $C \subseteq G$ of size $|C|$ , what is the probability of sampling this subset at random?

I think the probability can be calculated like this: $p = \frac{|C|!(|G|-|C|)!}{|G|!}$

However, lets say we have sampled a set $U$ that has $x$ elements of $C$ and $y$ elements of $G$. So, $|U \cap C| = x$ and $|U \cap (G\setminus C)| = y$.

What is the probability of this event? I would say:
p = $\frac{\binom{|C|}{x}\binom{|G|-|C|}{y}}{\binom{|G|}{|U|}}$

Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what that "$+1$" is doing in your first probability calculation, but otherwise your answers look good.

Comment: Yes, your right!

Comment: Yes, I agree, but let me point out that you should have made it clear how you sample. Apparently in the first case you sample uniformly from the set of all subsets of size $k=|C|$ and in the second case you sample uniformly from the set of all subsets of size $k=|U|$, but that is not the only option of course.